# Sum over zeta zeroes - how to handle conjugates?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Consider the prime counting function:

$$\pi(n)=R(x)-\sum\limits_\rho R\left(x^{\rho}\right)-\frac{1}{\text{ln } x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\text{ arctan }\frac{\pi }{\text{ln } x}$$

where $R$ is Riemann's function ([link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html)) and the $\rho$ are the zeroes of the zeta function, with the trivial zeroes easily summed (because they're the even negative integers), and the non-trivial zeroes taken in conjugate pairs in order of increasing imaginary part. Am I right in thinking that

$$\sum_{\rho} R(n^{\rho})=\sum _{\Im(\rho )\leq t} \left(R\left(n^{\bar{\rho
   }}\right)+R\left(n^{\rho }\right)\right)$$

Is this the right way to deal with the conjugate pairs?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. This sum doesn't converge absolutely, and such symmetric summing (and taking the limit as $t\to\infty$) is the correct way to understand this sum.

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'll tick it!